# How Lua tables work

Tags: lua

I am starting to learn Lua from Programming in Lua (2nd edition)
I didn't understand the following in the book. Its very vaguely explained.

a.) `w={x=0,y=0,label="console"}`

b.) `x={math.sin(0),math.sin(1),math.sin(2)}`

c.) `w[1]="another field"`

d.) `x.f=w`

e.) `print (w["x"])`

f.) `print (w[1])`

g.) `print x.f[1]`

When I do `print(w[1])` after a.), why doesn't it print `x=0`

What does c.) do?

What is the difference between e.) and `print (w.x)`?

What is the role of b.) and g.)?

Comment: BTW, there is no print *statement*, only a print *function*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to realize that this:

```
t = {3, 4, "eggplant"}
```

is the same as this:

```
t = {}
t[1] = 3
t[2] = 4
t[3] = "eggplant"
```

And that this:

```
t = {x = 0, y = 2}
```

is the same as this:

```
t = {}
t["x"] = 0
t["y"] = 2
```

Or this:

```
t = {}
t.x = 0
t.y = 2
```

In Lua, tables are not just lists, they are [associative arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array).

When you print `w[1]`, then what really matters is line c.) In fact, `w[1]` is not defined at all until line c.).

There is no difference between e.) and `print (w.x)`.

b.) creates a new table named `x` which is separate from `w`.

d.) places a reference to `w` *inside of `x`*. (NOTE: It does not actually make a copy of `w`, just a [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28computer_science%29). If you've ever worked with pointers, it's similar.)

g.) Can be broken up in two parts. First we get `x.f` which is just another way to refer to `w` because of line d.). Then we look up the first element of that table, which is `"another field"` because of line c.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. It really helped me in understanding. However I have one quick question.. When I do, x.f=w it means that I have something like x={f=w} and I am trying to print x.f. Since f=w and w= {"another field",x=0,y=0,label="console"}, so x={f={"another field",x=0,y=0,label="console"}}. Am I doing it right? If yes, should'nt print (x.f.label) give console as output?

Comment: Yes, that is all correct. Just remember that `x.f` actually refers to the same physical RAM as `w` does, so if you modify the values in `x.f`, the modifications will show up in `w`. However, if you replace `x.f` with another value (such as a different table,) `w` will no longer be affected.

Answer (score 2):

There's another way of creating keys in in-line table declarations.

```
x = {["1st key has spaces!"] = 1}
```

The advantage here is that you can have keys with spaces and any extended ASCII character.
In fact, a key can be literally anything, even an instanced object.

```
function Example()
    --example function
end
x = {[Example] = "A function."}
```

Any variable or value or data can go into the square brackets to work as a key. The same goes with the value.
Practically, this can replace features like the `in` keyword in python, as you can index the table by values to check if they are there.

Getting a value at an undefined part of the table will not cause an error. It will just give you nil. The same goes for using undefined variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
local w = {
    --[1] = "another field"; -- will be set this value
    --["1"] = nil;  -- not save to this place, different with some other language
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    label = "console";

}
local x = {
    math.sin(0);
    math.sin(1);
    math.sin(2);
}

w[1] = "another field" -- 
x.f  = w

print (w["x"])

-- because x.f = w
-- x.f and w point one talbe address
-- so value of (x.f)[1] and w[1] and x.f[1] is equal
print (w[1])
print ((x.f)[1])
print (x.f[1])

-- print (x.f)[1] this not follows lua syntax 
-- only a function's has one param and type of is a string
-- you can use print "xxxx"
-- so you print x.f[1] will occuur error


-- in table you can use any lua internal type 's value to be a key
-- just like

local t_key = {v=123}
local f_key = function () print("f123") end

local t = {}
t[t_key] = 1
t[f_key] = 2

-- then t' key actualy like use t_key/f_key 's handle 

-- when you user t[{}] = 123, 
-- value 123 related to this no name table {} 's handle
```